# System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html-select

I receive the error `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items` on this line:

```
@Html.DropDownList("empnames", new SelectList(ViewBag.empnames), "Select");
```

I want to get the corresponding `Emp_id` from the selected `Emp_Name` and want to update my table `Enq_Submission`.

My Model,Controller and Views are as follows:

**Model:**

```
namespace MvcConQuery.Models
{

[Table("Enq_Submission")]
public class EnquiryModel
{
private ConQueryDataClassesDataContext dc = new ConQueryDataClassesDataContext();
[Key]
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Int32 Enq_id { get; set; }
[Required]
[Display(Name="Name")]
public string CustomerName { get; set; }
[ReadOnly(true)]
public string Date
{
get
{
DateTime Date = DateTime.Now;
return Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); ;
}

set{}

}


[Required]
[Display(Name = "Region")]
public string Region { get; set; }
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Entered phone number format is not valid.")]
[Display(Name = "Phone number")]
public string Ph_No { get; set; }
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
[Display(Name = "Email_id")]
public string Email_id { get; set; }
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Address")]
public string Address { get; set; }
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Query")]
public string Query { get; set; }
public string Referral { get; set; }
public string Feedback { get; set; }
public string Status { get; set; }
public Int32? Emp_id { get; set; }
public string FollowUpDate { get; set; }
public List<EmployeeModel> Employees { get; set; }

}}

namespace MvcConQuery.Models
{
[Table("Employee_Details")]
public class EmployeeModel
{

[Key,Column(Order=0)]
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
//[ForeignKey("EnquiryModel")]
public Int32 Emp_id { get; set; }
public string Emp_Name{ get; set; }
//[Key,Column(Order=1)]
public string Region { get; set; }
//[ForeignKey("Region")]
public string Emp_PhNo { get; set; }
public string Emp_Address { get; set; }
public List<EnquiryModel> Enquires { get; set; }


}

}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{

EnquiryModel enquirymodel = db.Enquires.Find(id);
if (enquirymodel == null)
{
return HttpNotFound();
}
var rgn=enquirymodel.Region;
var empnames = (from ename in dc.GetTable<Employee_Detail>() where ename.Region ==rgn select ename.Emp_Name).ToList();
ViewBag.empnames = empnames;

return View(enquirymodel);

}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(EnquiryModel enquirymodel,string empnames)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{

var empid = (from eid in dc.GetTable<Employee_Detail>() where eid.Emp_Name == empnames select eid.Emp_id).First();
enquirymodel.Emp_id = empid;
db.SaveChanges();
}
return View(enquirymodel);
}
```

**View:**

```
@model MvcConQuery.Models.EnquiryModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Edit";

}
<style>
.myClass label{
font-weight:bold;
}
</style>

<h2>Allocate Employee</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
<legend>EnquiryModel</legend>
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Enq_id)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CustomerName)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Date)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Region)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Ph_No)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Email_id)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Address)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Query)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Referral)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Feedback)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Status)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FollowUpDate)
@Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Emp_id);


<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerName, new { @class = "label" })
</div>

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CustomerName)

<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Region, new { @class = "label" })
</div>

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Region)

<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ph_No, new { @class = "label" })
</div>

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Ph_No)

<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email_id, new { @class = "label" })
</div>

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email_id)

<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, new { @class = "label" })
</div>

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Address)<div class="editor-label">

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Query, new { @class = "label" })
</div>

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Query)


@Html.Label("Select Employee", new { @class = "label" })
@Html.DropDownList("empnames", new SelectList(ViewBag.empnames), "Select");

<p>
<input type="submit" value="Allocate" name="Submit"/>
</p>

</fieldset>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Can anyone help me in how I can solve this problem, please?

Comment: You have to much code in your question, please narrow it down to the problem lines. What action (first / second) gives the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was both 'Edit' expects the empnames ViewBag value to be filled.
Then the reason behind Not updating the table was missing a line of code in the controller, that is:

**db.Entry(enquirymodel).State = EntityState.Modified;**

[HttpPost]

```
    public ActionResult Edit(EnquiryModel enquirymodel,string empnames)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var rgn = enquirymodel.Region;
            var empnamess = (from ename in dc.GetTable<Employee_Detail>() where ename.Region == rgn select ename.Emp_Name).ToList();
            ViewBag.empnames = empnamess;

      var empid = (from eid in dc.GetTable<Employee_Detail>() where eid.Emp_Name == empnames select eid.Emp_id).First();

            db.Entry(enquirymodel).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(enquirymodel);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are in the `Edit` view.

In contrary to the first `Edit` action, the second doesn't have this line:

```
var empnames = (from ename in dc.GetTable<Employee_Detail>() where ename.Region ==rgn select ename.Emp_Name).ToList();
ViewBag.empnames = empnames;
```

Can you check if it helps adding that?

**EDIT:**

I don't think you understand the internal mechanism of MVC. When you return `View(...)` it renders the view with the same name as the method (`Edit` in your case). Since both render `Edit` it expects the `empnames` ViewBag value to be filled.

You can also try to return this in the second `Edit`:

```
ViewBag.empnames = new List<Employee_Detail>();
```

Comment: Sorry, we can't use that ,because in the scope of second edit 'empnames' has different meaning.

Comment: @user3350713: but you still render the same view. You must provide it.

Comment: I have 2 tables,Employee_table and work_table. i have a drop-down list, which is populated with employee_name from employee_table and want to update the work_table with the selected item from drop-down list. how can i do it in MVC4? pls help me...

Comment: @user3350713: I guess you are in the wrong place then, we only provide solutions for specific problems. For tutorials you should check MSDN for example.

Comment: @user3350713: I suggest to either rename one of the methods / views, or check in the View whether the value of `empnames` is null.

Comment: Yes,now its working . But the table does not get update.   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(EnquiryModel enquirymodel,string empnames)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
  { var rgn = enquirymodel.Region;
 var empnamess = (from ename in dc.GetTable<Employee_Detail>() where ename.Region == rgn select ename.Emp_Name).ToList();
                ViewBag.empnames = empnamess;
      var empid = (from eid in dc.GetTable<Employee_Detail>() where eid.Emp_Name == empnames select eid.Emp_id).First();
enquirymodel.Emp_id = empid;
db.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("Index");
 }

Comment: I guess you have the wrong action name in the View with the form.

Comment: `@using (Html.BeginForm())` must be `@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit2"))` or something like that

Comment: :The answer was helpful.ThankYou.